# Change default application for single file with terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, automation, sh

I'm creating an install `bash` script for a whole bunch of applications through Terminal on OSX that I'm planning on using to install on about 300 computers.

Right now it runs/installs `brew`, installs `ffmpeg`, updates `python` and installs a few programs, folders and scripts.

The last thing I can't figure out in the command line is how to force the `.sh` file that is created during the installation process to open in Terminal as a default when you click on it. Now I don't want to change all `.sh` files to open in Terminal, I just want the new file that I've created to open in Terminal as a default.

Comment: Could you change all the files to open .sh, then when you are done change it back?

Comment: I don't want to do that as I'll be installing this on machines across the country and I don't want to mess with their system settings that they may have associated to .sh files.

Comment: Just instead of `some_bash_script.sh` use `some_bash_script.command`. it will be opened by Terminal.app.

Comment: haha! And here I've been for the last 2 weeks trying everything I could think of and you solved it in 2 hours. That works! Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be more appropriate for apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use open to open a file with the default application.

If you want to open a file with an application other than the default one, put `-a` and specify the application to open with, such as

`open -a "terminal" ~/Desktop/filename.sh`

Comment: Thanks for this, but I want Terminal to become the default app for all the times they use the script, not just a single time.